# FreeType texture atlas completely white

Tags: opengl, freetype, freetype2

I'm following this tutorial to render texts using OpenGL: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_02

However, when I inspect the bitmap.buffer of each character loaded it is filled with 255, completely.
Then, when I render, all I can see is a white rectangle.

[image: Top white rectangle]
The rectangle I'm talking about is the one on the top (in the black viewport).

Answer (score 2):

Using GL_ALPHA won't work with OpenGL 3.2+.

The first solution I've tried is to replace GL_ALPHA with GL_RED and use .r on fragment shader, where the tutorial uses .a

Comment: It will actually work with OpenGL 3.2+. What it won't work with is a ***core*** profile. It was deprecated in OpenGL 3.0 and removed in 3.1, but if you have a *compatibility* profile you can continue to use `GL_ALPHA` textures. `GL_RED` is the better solution as you point out, however.